# Nvidia 555M driver installation problem with a Lenovo Y570

Tags: nvidia, lenovo, nvidia-optimus

I am trying to install the Nvidia 555M driver on my Lenovo Y570. I've tried all the advises here and other sites but I couldn't solve the problem.

1. I downloaded the graphics card driver from the nvidia site for linux X64
2. I tried to install it but a warning appears that I have to close x server.
3. I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and then type `sudo service lightdm stop` to stop the X server
4. After this I can easily install the NVIDIA driver. but there was a problem: I couldn't get back to x server when I typed `sudo service lightdm start`. Again the black screen appeared.
5. After deleting xorg.conf file I again can see the screen as opened as first installation of Ubuntu.

Edit: After trying too many things again the failure. I am adding what i tried till now. If you can help I will be very glad to you.

Thanks for your advise but it didn't work :( There is no problem with stopping lightdm and then installing nvidia driver for Geforce 555m. The main problem that I have to deal with is that `sudo service lightdm start` doesn't work after installation. A warning appears, saying "no screen found". Unless I delete /etc/X11/xorg.conf I cannot start the X server. so I couldn't install Bumblebee.

Then I tried this: after deleting the xorg.conf file to start with x server I copied xorg.conf.backup file to xorg.conf. I again tried to install Bumblebee and I get it but when I rebooted the laptop, the X server problem appeared again. I think main problem is to restart lightdm.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug in somewhere in the kernel or BIOS and not the driver. Have a look at these for a workaround:

1. You'll need to remove the drivers and xorg.conf file (look at the link in step 3 below)
2. Then install [the hack](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bbswitch/issues/2#issuecomment-3797568) for working around a kernel/BIOS issue.
3. Then proceed with [installing Bumblebee](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work/36936#36936)

Answer (score -1):

i think These is a Optimos graphic card... 
it worked on my gt 540m..

[ironhide](https://launchpad.net/~mj-casalogic/+archive/ironhide/)

http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/610