# How do I install Nvidia drivers on a Lenovo Ideapad Y570?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nvidia 555M driver installation problem with a Lenovo Y570](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111493/nvidia-555m-driver-installation-problem-with-a-lenovo-y570)

I just got myself a nice Lenovo ideapad Y570, first thing i did was load kubuntu on it

Everything was going smoothly until i tried to set up virtual box and realized my drivers werent allowing my nvidia gt 550m to communicate with my system at it's full potential.

So I updated my drivers, followed the instructions perfectly (or at least i'm 90% sure i did), everything installed without error, but now my resolution is stuck at 640x480, a long ways away from the native resolution ( i forget the specific resolution)

Any ideas as to what i can do to fix it? if any further information is needed please let me know.

Comment: Which instructions did you follow to install the drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Does your laptop provide nvidia optimus technology?

If yes you can find help [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/123298/55504).

I hope this helps